# Changing OpenVPN DHCP pool

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, dhcp

I have a config at the moment which is working almost fine until some clients connect, the server starts to kick the clients off from the server or something like that. As I have checked every clients get a good IP address and there is no IP address collision. The clients are using different certificates to connect. However I want to change this config to separate the DHCP range.

The current server config is this:

```
port 1194
proto udp

dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
topology subnet

push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd

client-to-client

keepalive 10 300
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nobody

persist-key
persist-tun

status /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 6
```

I would like to have dynamic IPs assigned from this range:
10.8.1.0 - 10.8.1.254

For this, I would like to use a /23, so 255.255.254.0

And I will assign static IPs from this range:
10.8.0.3 - 10.8.1.255 as 0.1 and 0.2 might be assigned to the server.

I will use this to push to client for static ip:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.5 255.255.254.0
```

Could you please help me to modify my config to achieve this?

So split my 10.8.0.0-10.8.1.255 range to two:

- static IPs: 10.8.0.4-10.8.0.255
- dynamic IPs: 10.8.1.0-10.8.1.254

I will have Linux and Windows clients too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK finally it is solved with some changes on the config file:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem

mode server
tls-server
topology subnet
push "topology subnet"
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 255.255.254.0
ifconfig-pool 10.8.1.0 10.8.1.253
route-gateway 10.8.0.1
push "route-gateway 10.8.0.1"

client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

client-to-client

keepalive 10 300
comp-lzo

user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun

status /etc/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 6
```

Comment: Nice that you shared your config. But it would have been more helpful for the others when you would've explained what you've changed and why.

Comment: ... As comments in the conf file !

Comment: This answer does not provide enough good information, the correct answer is the one from @mnme

Answer (score 9):

To piggyback on Zoltan Szabo's answer and to fulfill the clarifications requested in the comments, here is my take on an answer.

### How to change the DHCP address pool?

First things first, the answer to the initial question. There's probably something like `server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0` in your config. This directive will automatically allocate a DHCP pool with `ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.4 10.8.0.251`. If you try to specify the `ifconfig-pool` yourself, OpenVPN will complain that you can't use `server` and `ifconfig-pool` together. Now there are two ways to customize the DHCP address pool.

#### a) Use nopool

There is an option to force OpenVPN to not allocate a DHCP address pool. Just add the `nopool` argument at the end of the server directive and you can specify the pool yourself.

```
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 nopool
ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.100 10.8.0.200
```

#### b) Declare and customise the expanded `server` directive yourself

This solution is what was used by Zoltan and is a bit trickier, but let's you customise more aspects of the server. The [OpenVPN manual](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage) shows how the `server` directive is expanded. Building upon this, you can declare all the necessary options yourself. This is highly dependent on the topology and if you're using `dev tun` or `dev tap`.

I just add an example based on the configuration in the question (`topology subnet` and `dev tun`).

```
mode server
tls-server
push "topology subnet"
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.2 10.8.0.253 255.255.255.0
push "route-gateway 10.8.0.1"
route-gateway 10.8.0.1
```

See the notes below and the manual for more info.

### How to assign a static IP address to a client?

The second part of the question was about assigning static IPs. It seems like OP figured that one out, and there are already [plenty](https://dnaeon.github.io/static-ip-addresses-in-openvpn/) [of](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/openvpn-set-a-static-ip-address-for-a-client/) [resources](https://www.itsfullofstars.de/2018/09/openvpn-assign-static-ip-to-client/) about this topic on the internet. Nevertheless I would like to add a short paragraph about assigning static IP addresses to certain clients.

The solution is to use a client configuration directory and add a file for each client in there.

Add this to your OpenVPN server configuration:

```
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
```

If you want to, for example, assign the IP 10.8.0.5 to a client with the common name `client1`, create a file `/etc/openvpn/ccd/client1` with this content (note: this is for `topology subnet`):

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.5 255.255.255.0
```

Also keep the note in the [OpenVPN manual](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage) about `ifconfig-push` in mind. I couldn't find the `route` directive in the configuration Zoltan posted in his answer.

> Remember also to include a --route directive in the main OpenVPN config file which encloses local, so that the kernel will know to route it to the server's TUN/TAP interface.

### Notes

Just for completion, this is the section in the [OpenVPN manual](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage) about the expanding of the server directive.

> For example, `--server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0` expands as follows:
>
> ```
> mode server
> tls-server
> push "topology [topology]"
> if dev tun AND (topology == net30 OR topology == p2p):
>   ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2
>   if !nopool:
>     ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.4 10.8.0.251
>   route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
>   if client-to-client:
>     push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
>   else if topology == net30:
>     push "route 10.8.0.1"
>
> if dev tap OR (dev tun AND topology == subnet):
>   ifconfig 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0
>   if !nopool:
>     ifconfig-pool 10.8.0.2 10.8.0.253 255.255.255.0
>   push "route-gateway 10.8.0.1"
>   if route-gateway unset:
>     route-gateway 10.8.0.2
> ```